# Error: Failed to launch with output: Unable to create hosting process… c# interactive

Tags: visual-studio, c#-interactive

I have opened the `c# interactive` window in `Visual Studio`.
I get an error.

**Error:**
*Failed to launch*

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\managedlanguages\vbcsharp\languageservices\DesktopHost\InteractiveHost64.exe
```

*process (exit code: -1073741819) with output:*

*Failed to launch*

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\managedlanguages\vbcsharp\languageservices\DesktopHost\InteractiveHost64.exe'
```

*process (exit code: -1073741819) with output:*

*Unable to create a hosting process.*

**Question.**
How to fix the error?

**I use.**
Win `7x64`.
`Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 / 16.7.5`

**Picture-1**
[image]

---

### Update-1

I was using Visual Studio `cmd`.
**Description:**

- I ran `%comspec%/ k" C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\ Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat "`;
- I entered the command `cd c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\ 2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\managedlanguages\vbcsharp \ languageservices\DesktopHost\`
- I entered the command ʻInteractiveHost64.exe`;
- **result:**
  `System.ArgumentException: Expecting arguments: <server port> <semaphore name> <client process id> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Interactive.InteractiveHost.Service.RunServer (String [] args) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Interactive.InteractiveHostEntryPoint.Main (String [] args)`

Comment: What happens if you launch `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\managedlanguages\vbcsharp\languageservices\DesktopHost\InteractiveHost64.exe` from the command line?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I don't understand your proposal well.
Which command line to use?
If I understand correctly there is a Windows cmd, there is a Visual Studio cmd.
see `Update-1`.

Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: That tells you that `InteractiveHost64.exe` is there.

Comment: After the error occurs in Visual Studio, [report the problem from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio).